# Properties of a relation defined recursively

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, recurrence-relations, relations

We have the following recursively defined relation on the integers:
$$
(0,0) \in R \\
(a,b) \in R \implies (a+2, b+3) \in R \text{ and } (a+3, b+2) \in R
$$

The following are the questions of interest:

1. $5|a+b$ for $(a,b) \in R$
2. Is the reflexive closure of $R$ an equivalence relation?

I have attempted my proofs using induction. Is that a right way to go about it. Is there a direct proof. Note that for induction (traditionally at least) we try to prove that the statement is true for all integers whereas here the ordered pair $(a, b)$ form a double sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely prove facts about this by inducting on $n$, where $n$ is the first time $(a,b) \in R$. Perhaps this becomes more obvious if we write

- $R_0 = \big \{ (0,0) \big \}$
- $R_{n+1} = R_n \cup \big \{ (a+2,b+3) \mid (a,b) \in R_n \big \} \cup \big \{ (a+3,b+2) \mid (a,b) \in R_n \big \}$
- $R = \bigcup R_n$

So now, say you want to show that $5 \mid a+b$ always holds. We induct on the "birthday" of $(a,b)$. If you don't like the whimsical language, we induct on $n$ and work with $R_n$.

- If the birthday of $(a,b)$ is $0$, then $(a,b) = (0,0)$, and obviously $5 \mid 0 + 0$
- If instead, the birthday of $(a,b)$ is $n+1$, then either $(a,b) = (a' + 2, b' + 3)$ or $(a,b) = (a' + 3, b' + 2)$ for some element $(a',b')$ with birthday $n$. Now, by induction, we know that $5 \mid a' + b'$, so regardless of which case we're in, we find $a + b = a' + b' + 5$, and so $5 \mid a + b$ (as desired).

To see the claim about equivalence relations, since we're taking the reflexive closure, the question is whether $R$ is symmetric and transitive.

Symmetry probably won't be too hard. You know (by induction) that if $(a',b')$ has a smaller birthday, then $(b',a')$ must be in $R$ too. But we know how to make $(a,b)$ from $(a',b')$, and a similar argument will show how to make $(b,a)$ from $(b',a')$.

So the interesting case is transitivity. This is where I think experimentation is useful. You should try to actually build $R_n$ for small $n$. Maybe look at all elements with birthday at most $5$ or $6$. You can do it by hand, or you can get a programming language to do it for you. Do you see any patterns? Do you see how you might build a *counterexample* to transitivity? As a hint, we know that $5 \mid a+b$... That might be a good invariant to try and use.

---

I hope this helps ^_^